# Why does my SQL query select all rows when comparing date after casting?

Tags: c#, sql, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix with SQL Server Compact, and just have a simple question.  I have a line of code:

```
if(cndDateLastModified=="gteq"){stringCompiler+="'CAST(DateLastModified AS datetime)' >= 'CAST(" + DateLastModified + " AS datetime)' ";}////
```

By plotting the output on the screen the query specifically looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM POITable WHERE 'CAST(DateLastModified AS datetime)' >= 'CAST(09/25/2012 AS datetime)'
```

For some reason, it returns all rows before, on, and after the date specified.
I'm still a little green when it comes to querying, but by all researched accounts, this should work.  Clearly it is doing something I don't quite expect, which is understandable, considering.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work the way I want it?  Is it still trying to compare strings or some other format?

Note:  I did try this with CONVERT(datetime, DateLastModified) and CONVERT(datetime, DateLastModified, 1) for both conversions.

Another Note:  It is stored in the database as a string.

Another Note:  If I switch the condition (from >= to <=) it does the opposite and returns no rows, which I would kind of expect considering the first unexpected result set, but still don't know why.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are asking for all data that was modified up through yesterday (it is Sept 26 as of this posting). Do you have any data modified from today or tomorrow or the future that should be excluded?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the line after I changed to test it.  I have edited my post to reflect the appropriate line which includes the condition >= NOT <=, sry.

Comment: Using >=, is how i meant to post this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because with the single quotes you are comparing two strings. 'CAST(....)' vs. 'CAST(...)'. You may as well have written WHERE 'Ginger' >= 'Fred' you would get the same results. :D

What you should need is:
FROM POITable WHERE CAST(DateLastModified AS datetime) >= CAST('09/25/2012' AS datetime)

Use the single quotes around the literal date. '09/25/2012'

However if you're using SQL server, you can just use WHERE CAST(DateLastModified AS datetime) >= '2012-09-25'

Additionally, if the DateLastModified column of the table is already a date time, remove the cast. Cast is for converting strings to data types. My hunch is all you need is:

```
WHERE DateLastModified >= '2012-09-25' /* ISO date strings are understood and accepted by SQL Server. */
or
WHERE DateLastModified >= GETDATE() /*Everything in the future, time inclusive.*/
or
WHERE DateLastModified >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) /* Everything starting today. */
```

Comment: Well, I tried it your way with this line (remember, I am not comparing it to a static date, I am using a C# variable from an html form) The line of code with your suggestion has been modified to:

Comment: if(cndDateLastModified=="gteq"){stringCompiler+="CAST('DateLastModified' AS datetime) >= CAST('" + DateLastModified + "' AS datetime) ";}////

Comment: I get this error:
Server Error in '/' Application.

There was a syntax error in the date format. [ Expression = DateLastModified ]

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was a syntax error in the date format. [ Expression = DateLastModified ]

Comment: Okay, I've got it, I need to add the single quotes to the second expression but not the first, since it is just pulling a database column.  Thanks for your help, you were the closest to helping so I am accepting your answer.  Thanks Again to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this

```
stringCompiler+="CAST(DateLastModified AS datetime) >= CAST('" + DateLastModified + "' AS datetime) "
```

Note the position of the single quote has changed

That gives you

```
CAST(DateLastModified AS datetime) >= CAST('09/25/2012' AS datetime)
```